# Checkout a Git tree object into working dir?

Tags: git

I have constructed a tree that contains a couple of files and only exists in the object database. I then added it to the index associated with a path, and committed:

```
git hash-object -w --stdin
...
abcd1
git hash-object -w --stdin
...
abcd2

git mktree
100755 blob abcd1 a.txt 
100755 blob abcd2 b.txt

# resultant tree sha1:
abc123

git update-index --index-info
100755 tree abc123 fake.tree.path

git commit -m "fake.tree.path tree commit"
```

This seems to work, but what I want is to be able to then:

```
git checkout fake.tree.path
```

And have "a.txt" and "b.txt" written into the working dir. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what I was doing wrong was this:

```
git update-index --index-info
100755 tree abc123 fake.tree.path
```

should have been this:

```
git update-index --index-info
040000 tree abc123 fake.tree.path
```

Now doing a `git checkout fake.tree.path` constructs the directory as desired.

Answer (score 1):

1. empty index `git read-tree --empty`
2. read tree object into index `git read-tree <tree-isha>`
3. empty working directory except directory *.git* `ls -a | grep -vw .git | xargs rm -fr | xargs rm -fr`
4. checkout index into working tree `git checkout-index -a`

**references**

- Git Pro 2nd ed. Chapter 10 Git Internals. [enter link description here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2)